# API outbound callout: Confused limits

Tags: apex, rest-api, limits

Scenario:

Making Apex outbound calls to `GET /ui-api/object-info/{objectApiName}/picklist-values/{recordTypeId}/{fieldApiName}` via a Named credential.

```
    String endpoint = 'callout:Salesforce_API_Access/' + objectType + '/picklist-values/' + recordTypeId + '/' + fieldName;
    
    
    EncodingUtil.urlEncode(endpoint,'UTF-8');
    
    // Call the API in order to get the values 
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    
    //req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + getSessionIdFromVFPage());
    req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json '); 
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
    req.setMethod('GET');
    Http http = new Http();
    
    HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
```

Here apart from **apex per transaction**, which limit of 100 api calls, will 24 hour api limit also get hit, as it is the self org which is getting hit.
Will the inbound API calls be calculated against this org rolling 24 hour limits?

Is there a documentation supporting if the 24 hour rolling period limit doesn't get hit?

Comment: This question, and the previous, suggests that you might be in an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Have you looked at [getPicklistValues](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_picklist_values) as an alternative? If it didn't work, why not?

Comment: yeah this is custom LWC, which cannot be used as we have used omniscript components here. So cannot mix both Custom LWC and OmniScript. I mean technically we can, but it creates other problems with validations. So wanted to usee only omnistuido whcih allows us to fetch picklist values from Record Type/